# Directive inside directive and ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that uses another directive.

The main directive, slipt a string to edit each item separately.

The problem is that the main directive doesn't receibe the ng-model changes from the inner directive.

Use the example below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="values">
    <editors model="values">

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.values = '1 2';
        }]);

        app.directive('editors', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<accordion><accordion-group heading="Editor 1 - {{field1}}"><editor model="field1"></accordion-group><accordion-group heading="Editor 2 - {{field2}}"><editor model="field2"></accordion-group>',
                scope: {
                    model: '=model'
                },
                controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.$watch('model', function() {
                        var values = $scope.model.split(' ');
                        $scope.field1 = values[0];
                        $scope.field2 = values[1];

                        $('body').append($scope.field1 + ' - ');
                        $('body').append($scope.field2+ '<br>');
                    });
                }]
            };
        });

        app.directive('editor', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model"> {{model}}',
                scope: {
                    model: '=model'
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Image 1 - Changing the value in the field1 (Editor 1) doesn't affect the accordion title.

Iamge 2 - Changing the root value (input outside accordion) updates the fields (field1 and field2) and accordion heading.

[image: Image 1 and 2]

How can I get it working, when I change the Editor 1 value to update accordion heading ?

Answer (score 0):

NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER use the prefix "ng" in your own custom directives!!!!

`ng-model` is a directive developped and maintained by angular. It will create its own scope.

It is supposed to receive a string and nothing else.

Just bind it that way :

```
            scope: {
                model: '=model'
            },
```